# "g++" works in Command Prompt but not in VSCode Terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw32

When I type "g++" in Windows Command Prompt, I get this message "g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.". However, when I try that in the VSCode terminal, I get this message instead "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It (g++.exe) needs to be in your PATH, one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I restarted my computer and that fixed the problem.